# Frame layout Priority

Tags: android, android-framelayout

Is there any way to set priorities for frame layouts.. My issue is. 
Every time i load my Activity. it will show the 3rd frame layout first as it contains a listView. 
I need the first framelayout to show first. First and Second frame layout contains some text and buttons. I'm using a helper class to load the listview view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/first">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/first"
            android:id="@+id/second">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/second"
            android:id="@+id/third">

        </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here is my helper class

Comment: If you are putting all frame-layout below to next then why you are using Relative layout, use LinearLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout_weight, set total weight in the root element at 100.

Then in the first give 20, second 20 and at the third 60, so they are displayed in order.
You can play with the percentage